# Java wildcard generic not allowed?

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

So I want to make a util method, that returns a List with errors from `ConstraintValidator`s. I have this method:

```
public static List<String> getViolationsToList(Set<ConstraintViolation<?>> violations) {
    List<String> errors = new ArrayList<>();
    for(ConstraintViolation<?> violation: violations) {
        errors.add(violation.getMessage());
    }

    return errors;
}
```

However when I call it,

```
RestUtil.getViolationsToList(violations);
```

It does not compile. Violations is of type:

```
Set<ConstraintViolation<UserDto>> violations;
```

any ideas? Eclipse suggest to remove the wildcard with UserDto or create new method, but I want to use generics.

Comment: Try to use: `Set<ConstraintViolation<Object>` instead of `Set<ConstraintViolation<?>`

Comment: Try: Set<ConstraintViolation<? super UserDto>

Comment: This clearly won't compile. ConstraintViolation<String> does not inherit ConstraintViolation<Object>, despite String does inherit Object. 
I tried and ? extends Object, but still does not work.

Comment: @AdamKortylewicz I want to make it generic, to work for all dtos. hardcoding a given DTO is not a good idea.

Comment: What's the top-level DTO type called, then? `Dto`?

Comment: it is just a pojo, so its super class is Object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
Set<<ConstraintViolation<T>>
```

Then:

```
public static <T> List<String> getViolationsToList(Set<ConstraintViolation<T>> violations) {
```

Comment: Did not work, but using only T worked. Thanks alot.
public static <T> List<String> getViolationsToList(Set<ConstraintViolation<T>> violations) {

Answer (score 3):

Generics are invariant. `Set<ConstraintViolation<UserDto>>` is not a subtype of `Set<ConstraintViolation<?>>`, even though `ConstraintViolation<UserDto>` is a subtype of `ConstraintViolation<?>`. This is just like how `List<String>` is not a subtype of `List<Object>`, even though `String` is a subtype of `Object`.

You need a wildcard at the top level in order to get polymorphism of type arguments:

```
List<String> getViolationsToList(Set<? extends ConstraintViolation<?>> violations) {
```

Answer (score 1):

To dig a bit further,

OP does not mention it, but note that the code is working in Java 8 due to better type inference.

In java 8 you could do the following :

`return violations.stream().map(Violation::getMessage).collect(Collectors.toList());`

which is a bit more elegant

Comment: Yes, I didn't mention the project is in java 7.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are trying to do something like this :

```
public static <T> List<String> getViolationsToList(Set<ConstraintViolation<T>>    violations) {
        List<String> errors = new ArrayList<>();
        for(ConstraintViolation<T> violation: violations) {
            errors.add(violation.getMessage());
        }

        return errors;
    }
```